# Merge/Update string value in Python list

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do you merge two lists as below?

```
list1 = ['A', 'B', 'C']
list2 = ['12', '34', '54']
```

I would like to the following result :

```
final_list = ['A=12', 'B=34', 'C=54']
```

Note that I would need to add a '=' between each value of each list.

The goal is to have a comma delimited list.

Looping through each list1 to append the list2 element returns a *"'str' object has no attribute 'append'"* error :

```
for x in range(0, len(list1)):
    list1[x].append(list2[x])
```

Answer (score 4):

You can make use of **[`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)** to iterate both lists at the same time and concatenate both items using `f-strings`.

```
final_list = [f'{i}={j}' for i, j in zip(list1, list2)]
```

Answer (score 3):

```py
>>> list1 = ['A', 'B', 'C']
>>> list2 = ['12', '34', '54']
>>> [f"{a}={b}" for a,b in zip(list1, list2)]
['A=12', 'B=34', 'C=54']
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```py
final_list = list(map('='.join, zip(list1, list2)))
```

Outputs:

```py
['A=12', 'B=34', 'C=54']
```

Answer (score 2):

This will work:

```
list1 = ['A', 'B', 'C']
list2 = ['12', '34', '54']
final_list=[]
for x in range(len(list1)):
    final_list.append(list1[x]+"="+list2[x])
print(final_list)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution:

```py
list1, list2 = ["A", "B", "C"], ["12", "34", "54"]
merged_list = []
for index, item in enumerate(list1):
    merged_list.append(f"{item}={list2[index]}")
```